# Prove that Steifel Manifold as a Manifold Using Group Action

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, lie-groups, group-actions

The Stiefel Manifold is the space of $k$-tuples of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$
$$
V_k\left(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}\right)=\left\{\left(v_1, \ldots, v_k\right): e_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n+k},\left\langle v_i, v_j\right\rangle=\delta_{i, j}\right\}
$$

I am trying to show that Steifel Manifold can be endowed with a smooth structure by relating it to $O(n+k)$ i.e. realizing $O(n)$ as a submatrix of $O(n+k)$

$$
O(n) \hookrightarrow O(n+k), \quad O(n) \ni B \mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}
I_{k, k} & 0_{k, n} \\
0_{n, k} & B
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then $O(n)$ group acts on $O(n+k)$ is:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
A_{k, k} & A_{k, n} \\
A_{n, k} & A_{n, n}
\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{cc}
I_{k, k} & 0_{k, n} \\
0_{n, k} & B
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
A_{k, k} & A_{k, n} B \\
A_{n, k} & A_{n, n} B
\end{array}\right)
$$
The action is free (?) and proper. If I can prove
$$
\pi: O(n+k) \rightarrow V_k\left(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}\right)
$$
as a projection $O(n+ k) \xrightarrow{i} \mathbb{R}^{(n+k)^2}\to V_k\left(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}\right)\subset \mathbb{R}^{(n+k)\times k} $ that satisfies:

$$\pi(Q_1) = \pi(Q_2) \leftrightarrow Q_2 = Q_1 B \quad \text{for some B} \in O(n)\quad (*)$$
Then a bijection
$$O(n+k)/O(n) \cong V_k\left(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}\right)$$
can be established. Upgrade this bijection to diffeomorphism is quite easy and it is not in the scope of this question.

A second thought raises 2 questions:

1. Why the action is free? In other words, $A_{k,n} B = A_{k,n} \Rightarrow B= I$. But is it the case here?
2. Denote the submatrix of $Q_1,Q_2$ as $(Q_1)_{k,n}$ and $(Q_2)_{k,n}$. Is it true that
   there exists $B \in O(n)$ such that $(Q_2)_{k,n} = (Q_1)_{k,n} B$ ?

Both of these 2 questions are just linear algebra. But I could not think out a property of orthogonal matrix that can be applied here.

**Edit: Maybe I overthink this problem... I do not think these sub-matrix are actually relevant for this proof.**

Thanks in Advance!

Answer:
1)
Let $A \in O(n+k), B \in O(n)$ such that $AB = I$. Then since $I = (AB)^T(AB)$, $B = I$, which means the action is free.
2) Let $F: O(n+k)/O(n) \to V_k$ defined to be $\pi_F(Q O(n)) = F([Q])$.
Surjectivity follows from the definition of $\pi$. The non-trivial part is to prove the injectivity i.e. to prove (*):
If $\pi(Q) = \pi(M)$, $Q$ and $M$ agrees on the first k-columns. The remaining $n$ columns constitute a $n$-orthonormal tuples in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$. Denote $\alpha$ to be the last $n$-columns for $Q$ and $\beta$ to be the last $n$-columns for $M$. Then a linear transformation from an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis is an orthogonal transformation, with a corresponding matrix orthogonal basis $B \in O(n)$. Since the transformation does not change the first $k$ columns, we have $Q = M \cdot B$.

Comment: If a subgroup $H$ of $G$ acts on $G$ via multiplication, this is always free.